# Why does require_once() fail when I use PHPUnit in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I successfully installed PHPUnit and now I'm trying to make it work with Zend Framework 1.x. I checked everywhere different ways to do it but none of them work for me because every time I execute the PHPUnit command in my "tests" folder I get the following error:

> Warning: require_once(Zend/xxxxxxxxx.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\square\tests\TestHelper.php on line 12"

where xxxxxxx.php is Application.php, Autoloader.php, etc.

So I came to the conclusion that, PHPUnit or Bootstrap doesn't find my Zend library. Weird, because I don't have any problems when I run my project in my production|developer environment (where the route to Zend is added in php.ini).

**phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./TestHelper.php">
    <testsuite>
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8"
            yui="true" highlight="true"
            lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./log/testdox.html" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

**TestHelper.php**

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/**
 * Register autoloader
 */
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/../tests/application/ControllerTestCase.php';
```

Comment: The error message normally shows the include path it checked when including the file. Is your library folder there? If not, you need to try and work out why the `set_include_path` in your TestHelper is not working.

Comment: Is something that I don't understand, ¿Why the library folder is important?. My Zend library is located in my Wamp folder and referenced via php.ini: include_path = "C:\wamp\bin\library". I tried copying the Zend library inside library and tests/library folders and still have the same problem

Comment: What's important is that the Zend folder exists within your include path. It doesn't matter whether that's in `C:\wamp\bin\library` or within the library folder of your application. If you get the same error message either way then my first comment still applies - you need to see whether the include path has been set correctly.

Comment: I supose you talk about the include path in the php.ini; because I included it otherwise my zend application wouldn't run. Are there other ways to assure that the Zend library is included when I work with PHPUnit ? I hope you can give me some clues.

Comment: You are setting the include path in the code you posted. It's that that doesn't seem to be working.